# Spring root context is not loaded via @ImportResource

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-data, spring-java-config

I have a small issue, i'm trying to combine java-based config with xml-based-config, i have a small issue, is that the configuration of my root-context is xml based, and i'm trying to scan it using **@ImportResource** annotation but spring during start can't read the configuration file which leads to beanCreationException, could not autowire fields.

here are my files

**RootConfig.java**

```
    @Configuration
    @ImportResource({ "classpath*: applicationContext.xml" })
    public class RootContextConfiguration {
        public RootContextConfiguration() {
            super();
        }
    }
```

**WebAppInitilizer.java**

```
    public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { RootContextConfiguration.class, SecurityContextConfiguration.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
            return new Class[] { ServletContextConfiguration.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
            return new String[] { "/" };
        }
    }
```

**org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private ma.xxx.net.repos.UserRepository ma.xxx.net.service.impl.UserServiceImpl.userRepository;**

I presume it couldn't inject bean because it couldn't find it.

This is spring-data-managed Repository.

```
    @Repository
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>{

    }
```

This is what you asked for

```
    @Service("userService")
    public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService {

        @Autowired
        private UserRepository userRepository;

        @Override
        public User getUser() {
            return userRepository.findOne(1L);
        }
    }
```

Hope you guys can help me out with this.

Comment: Can you show your config?and how you autowired repository bean into service also

Comment: Don't presume. Add a really simple bean to your root context, printing to System.out, to see if the root context instantiates its beans or not.

Comment: Can you show you applicaitonContext.xml and the stacktrace so we can get more info on the exception?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your config `@EnableJpaRepositories` and point to a package where the repository exist

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "your.repository.package")
```